# How to compute the count by a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have the following table (call it just `table`):

```
id       name         value      group_id
PK    varchar(32)    integer     integer
```

Now, I need to write a query that returns me `SUM(value)` grouped by `group_id` and `COUNT(name)` where `name like '%me%'`( I don't need to just compute count grouped by `group_id`, I need to compute the count satisfies by the condition).

But, I need to do that without writing subqueries, and I'm limited to 9.2. I tend to write a custom aggregate function specific for that needs. Would it be a right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 9.4 you can use a filtered aggregate:

```
select group_id, 
       sum(value)
       count(name) filter (where name like '%me%')
from the_table
group by group_id;
```

For earlier versions, you need to use a CASE statement:

```
select group_id, 
       sum(value)
       count(case when name like '%me%' then 1 end) 
from the_table
group by group_id;
```

This works because aggregates will ignore null values and the `case` statement will return a `NULL` if the name doesn't match

Comment: Cool, thank you, but what if I in 9.2? Will I have to write a custom aggreagtes?

Comment: @St.Antario: see my edit (or upgrade to the current version ;) )

Comment: Got it. I have one more question that doesn't directly to the topic. Should we avoid writing custom aggregates? I just tried to find a case where they would be useful, but failed...

Comment: @St.Antario If you aren't on the current version always specify your version in the question. As for custom aggregates I've found them really handy, but don't use them often.

Comment: @St.Antario: there is no reason to _avoid_ custom aggregates. But if there is a "native" way of doing it, that will most probably be faster.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wow. I missed the addition of filter support to aggregates. That's *great*.

Answer (score 2):

It should be noted that case can be replaced by casting a bool to int which is shorter (`LIKE` can be replaced by `~~` but that is both shorter and less readable).

```
SELECT   group_id 
         ,Sum(value) AS sum_value
         ,Sum((name LIKE '%me%')::int) AS count_value 
FROM     table
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional aggregation

```
SELECT GROUP_ID, 
       SUM(VALUE) as SUM_VALUE
       SUM(CASE WHEN NAME LIKE '%ME%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as COUNT_VALUE
FROM 
    TABLE
GROUP BY 
    GROUP_ID;
```

Also see how CASE expression is vey handy https://exploresql.com/2015/08/18/multipurpose-case-expression/